# BERT Model Evaluation Measure in terms of Syntax Correctness and Semantic Coherence

Tags: machine-learning, syntax, nlp, semantics, bert-language-model

For example I have an original sentence. The  word **barking** corresponds to the word that is missing.

```
Original Sentence : The dog is barking.
Incomplete Sentence : The dog is ___________.
```

For example, using the BERT model, it predicts the word crying instead of the word barking.
How will I measure the accuracy of the BERT Model in terms of how syntactically correct  and semantically coherent the predicted word is?

(For an instance, there are a lot of incomplete sentences, and the task is to evaluate BERT accuracy based on these incomplete sentences.)Please help.

Comment: Is a dog not allowed to cry? Seems like a perfect sentence, both syntacticly and semanticly...

Answer (score 1):

For *syntax*, you can use for instance [English Resource Grammar](https://github.com/delph-in/erg) to decide if a sentence is grammatical. It is the biggest manually curated description of English grammar, you can try an [online demo](http://erg.delph-in.net/logon). A grammar (given it has a sufficiently large coverage which they usually don't) refuses to parse ungrammatical sentences, unlike statistical/neural parser that happily parses everything (and usually better than grammars).

Estimating *semantic plausibility* is a very difficult task and given that BERT is probably one of the best current language models, you cannot use another language model as a reference. There are some academic papers that deal with modeling semantic plausibility, you can start, e.g., with [this one from NAACL 2018](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N18-2049.pdf).